# How to use Json data type in C# Entity Framework model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

```
model.cs

[Column(TypeName = "json")]
    public string application_role { get; set; }
```

Its MySQL, data type of particular column is `json`, and how to add it in a model class. I tried with DataAnnotations but getting error as

```
The specified type member 'application_role' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

Linq Query to get data

```
context.sc_employee_details
                    .Where(e => e.user_name.Equals(userName))
                    .Select(o => o.application_role).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Why not use it as string only? just serialize and deserialize ?

Comment: PraveenR You will need to serialize and deserialize json data as @Hey24sheep has indicated. I don't think you can handle json any other way.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya removed DataAnnotations but still same error

Comment: @PraveenR I meant something like this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya I got it,  some what like this? `get
            {
                var ser = new JsonSerializer();
                ///
    ..
                return ser.Deserialize<Car[]>(jr);
            }
            set
            {
                var ser = new JsonSerializer();
                //...
   
            }`

Answer (score 5):

It might be a bit late, but EF on MySQL supports JSON format, here is [announcement](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/14).
Basically, you have to define an attribute like this one:

```
public JsonObject<string[]> Tags { get; set; } // Json storage
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You will do something like this

```
   private string _application_role;
   public string application_role 
   { 
       get{
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(_application_role)
         } 
       set{
           _application_role = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
         } 
   }
```

Or if you do not want to edit your model then you could do something like this

```
var myRole = context.sc_employee_details
                    .Where(e => e.user_name.Equals(userName))
                    .Select(o => o.application_role).SingleOrDefault();

if(myRole != null){
  var desRole = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(myRole);
}
```