# How to read JSON data column in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I created a database with JSON columns in mysql.
API defined in Swagger.
Writing JSON to the database works without problems, but when reading, the value of the JSON field is shown as an escaped string and not JSON

Here is part of model:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets Doc
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name="doc")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Doc { get; set; }
```

I also tried with string type and Dictionary<string, object> but unsuccessful.

Get method is here:

```
public virtual IActionResult GetDataById([FromRoute][Required]int? dataId, [FromRoute][Required]string jsonNode)
    { 
       if(_context.Data.Any( a => a.Id == dataId)) {
          var dataSingle = _context.Data.SingleOrDefault( data => data.Id == dataId);
              return StatusCode(200, dataSingle);
            } else {
                return StatusCode(404);
            }
        }
}
```

And resulting JSON resposne looks like this one:

```
{  
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "doc": "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\",\"key3\":{\"subkey3-1\":\"value3-1\",\"subkey3-2\":\"value3-2\"}}"
}
```

but correct JOSN should be linke this one:

```
{  
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "doc": {
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":"value2",
       "key3":{
               "subkey3-1":"value3-1",
               "subkey3-2":"value3-2"
              }
          }
   }
```

If I try to return just "Doc" (JSON) field, response JSON is properly formatted.

I tried different serialization/deserialization but unsuccessful.

If I have **public Dictionary<string, string> Doc { get; set; }** in Model I got error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM1VN0F0I0IM", Request id "0HM1VN0F0I0IM:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Data.Doc' is of type 'Dictionary<string, string>' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'
```

and for **public string Doc { get; set; } in Model** I got "doc" field value as escaped string as I mention above.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: As I know, EF does not support JSON column. Should place as string and parse it by 3rd party library such like Json.NET.

Comment: EF support JSON type since 2016. but nothing of this works now
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455701/how-to-use-json-data-type-in-c-sharp-entity-framework-model

Comment: You're right. That is just an alias of data type. Need to parse by other library. You linked case is supported by the connector library not EF itself.

Answer (score 0):

A few days later I found a resolution.

You need a one helper method that converts a string to object, exactly JObject if you use Json.NET - Newtonsoft.

```
public static JObject getJsonOutOfData (dynamic selectedData)
{
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedData); 
        var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data);

        if (selectedData.Doc != null) {
            JObject doc = JObject.Parse(selectedData.Doc);
            JObject docNode = JObject.Parse("{\"doc\":" + doc.ToString() + "}");
            var jsonDoc = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(docNode.ToString());
            jsonData.Property("doc").Remove();

            jsonData.Merge(jsonDoc, new JsonMergeSettings 
            {
                MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
            });
        }
        return jsonData;
}
```

and call it in the IActionResult method

```
public virtual IActionResult GetDataById([FromRoute][Required]int? accidentId, [FromRoute][Required]string jsonNode)
{ 
    if (_context.Data.Any( a => a.Id == accidentId)) {

        var accidentSingle = _context.Data.SingleOrDefault( accident => accident.Id == accidentId);

        var result = getJsonOutOfData(accidentSingle); 

        return StatusCode(200, result.ToString());

    } else {

        return StatusCode(404);
    }
}
```

In order to use unescaped JSON in POST/PUT requests, you should have a string type as a property type of JSON filed in the database model,  and create an additional "request" model and set JSON property as "Object" type:

Database Model:

```
[DataMember(Name="doc")]
public string Doc { get; set; }
```

Request Model:

```
[DataMember(Name="doc")]
public Object Doc { get; set; }
```

For example Create model looks like:

```
public virtual IActionResult CreateData([FromBody]DataCreateRequest body)
{          
    var accidentObject = new Data() {
        ColumnOne = body.ColumnOne,
        ColumnTwo = body.ColumnTwo,
        ColumnThree = body.ColumnThree,
        Doc = (bodyDoc != null) ? body.Doc.ToString() :  "{}"
        
    };

    _context.Data.Add(accidentObject);

    _context.SaveChanges();            
        
    return StatusCode(200, getJsonOutOfData(accidentObject));

}
```